# Publish Visual basic error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio, visual-basic-6

Boa noite amigos. Estou com uma dificuldade ao compilar meu projeto. Ele apresenta esse erro. O que pode ser? [image: erro]

Comment: Já tentou iniciar o Visual Studio como Administrador? Você tem os privilégios para acessar a pasta C:\ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu erro:

> Failed to copy file 'C:\Users\Rodrigo\Desktop\pacote\pacoteprograma\bin\Debug\app.publish\setup.exe' to 'C:/setup.exe'. Unable to add 'setup.exe' to Web site. Unable to add file 'setup.exe'. Acesso negado.

Ele está tentando colocar o `setup.exe` na pasta raiz (`C:\`). O windows não permite esse tipo de coisa sem permissão de administrador (e mesmo se permitisse, seria uma péssima ideia, não é a toa que ele não permite). Por causa disso que o resultado é o "Acesso negado".

Você tem que configurar no campo "*Publishing Folder location (ftp server or file path):*" que está aí na sua tela para uma pasta que seja adequada para colocar os seus arquivos compilados.

Comment: Show de bola amigao sem palavras (y)